# Tom-Select won't clear input when reset button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, tom-select

I'm using tom-select on my django form. On the form I also make a reset button to clear all input fields. All input values are cleared when I click the button, except the one using tom-select.

`form.py`

```
class ItemInputForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemInputForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                ....
                Column('item', css_class = 'col-md-4'),
                css_class = 'row'
                ),
                ....
            Div(
                HTML('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger col-md-4 me-4"><i class="fa-solid fa-print"></i> Print</button>'),
                HTML('<button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning col-md-4"><i class="fa-solid fa-rotate-left"></i> Reset</button>'),
                css_class = 'text-center'
                ),
                ....
```

tom-select on the `template`

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
      var item_select = new TomSelect("#id_item",{
        create: false,
        placeholder: 'Search',
        valueField: 'value',
        searchField: 'text',
        maxItems: 1,
        closeAfterSelect: true,
        render: {
              option: function(data, escape) {
                  return '<div>' + '<span class="text">' + escape(data.text) + '</span>' + '<span class="value">' + escape(data.value) + '</span>' + '</div>';
            },
          item: function(data, escape) {
                  return '<div title="' + escape(data.value) + '">' + escape(data.text) + '</div>';
                },
          },
      });
      item_select.clear();
```

When I refresh the page, the input field is clear because of `item_select.clear()`, but it didn't work if I want to clear with reset button. How to clear the tom-select input with reset button?

Answer (score 1):

I was confronted to the same issue, and here is my solution.

I enable tom-select for each HTML element having the `tom-select-enabled` class.
I use the `tomselected` class to fetch all tom-select enabled elements of a form on reset, and call the `tomselect.clear()` method.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Select all elements having the class 'tom-select-enabled', and enable TomSelect for these elements.
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".tom-select-enabled")
    .forEach((tomSelectElement) => {
      console.log(`Enabling tom-select for #${tomSelectElement.id}`);
      var tomSelectItem = new TomSelect(tomSelectElement, {
        plugins: {
          clear_button: { title: "Vider" }
        },
        create: false,
        persist: false
      });
    });

  // Clear all TomSelect instances of forms on reset.
  document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach((formElement) => {
    formElement.addEventListener("reset", (event) => {
      event.target
        .querySelectorAll(".tomselected")
        .forEach((tomselectedElement) => {
          tomselectedElement.tomselect.clear();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

As far as I could find, the `reset` event is not triggered for the element once `TomSelect` is instantiated.

Another issue is that the `clear()` method visually empty the tom-select field, but if the initial `select` field has a `selected="selected"` `<option>`, it set the `select` value to its selected option default.

If filed two issues on the subject:

- [Tom Select enabled field does not react to form reset events #544](https://github.com/orchidjs/tom-select/issues/544).
- [clear() method empty the visible tom-select field, but set the select field to the default selected option #545](https://github.com/orchidjs/tom-select/issues/545).

I've found some tips on how to clean my code in [How to clear existing (dynamically created) instances of Tom-Select #170](https://github.com/orchidjs/tom-select/discussions/170?sort=top).